# What is the difference between the TDAP and DTAP vaccines?

Tags: immune-system, vaccination

What is the difference between the TDAP and DTAP vaccines? Some nurses/pharmacists told me they are the same, but I am not convinced.

If they are the same then why would some organizations request for you to specifically have the TDAP vaccine and won't accept the DTAP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are similiar, but for different age group.

- DTAP for people under 7
- TDAP for 11 and up basically.

[WebMD](http://www.m.webmd.com/children/dtap-and-tdap-vaccines)

> DTaP is a vaccine that helps children younger than age 7 develop
>   immunity to three deadly diseases caused by bacteria: diphtheria,
>   tetanus, and whooping cough (pertussis). Tdap is a booster
>   immunization given at age 11 that offers continued protection from
>   those diseases for adolescents and adults.

They both cover the same illnesses, as well. The DTap probably isn't accepted due to the fact that it usually is taken around 7 years and so needs the booster shot TDap.

Comment: what if an adult took DTAP again instead of TDAP, would it be less effective?

Comment: This would probably benefit from a different question. But the answer can be found here http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/726330 . But no it wouldn't be less effective it would be more, the dtap is more antigen, the tdap is a booster. They would have a reaction to it, but be vacinated still.